# fsolve problems with the starting point

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, simpy

I'm using fsolve in order to solve a non linear equation. My problem is that, depending on the starting point the solutions change and I am not sure that the ones that I found are the most reasonable.
This is the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve, brentq,newton


A = np.arange(0.05,0.95,0.01)


PHI = np.deg2rad(np.arange(0,90,1))

def f(b):
    return np.angle((1+3*a**4-3*a**2)+(a**4-a**6)*(np.exp(2j*b)+2*np.exp(-1j*b))+(a**2-2*a**4+a**6)*(np.exp(-2j*b)+2*np.exp(1j*b)))-Phi  


B = np.zeros((len(A),len(PHI)))
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(PHI)):
        a = A[i]
        Phi = PHI[j]
        b = fsolve(f, 1)
        B[i,j]= b
```

I fixed x0 = 1 because it seems to give the more reasonable values. But sometimes, I think the method doesn't converge and the resulting values are too big.

What can I do to find the best solution?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The eternal issue with turning non-linear solvers loose is having a really good understanding of your function, your initial guess, the solver itself, and the problem you are trying to address.

I note that there are many (a,Phi) combinations where your function does not have real roots. You should do some math, directed by the actual problem you are trying to solve, and determine where the function should have roots.  Not knowing the actual problem, I can't do that for you.

Also, as noted on a (since deleted) answer, this is cyclical on b, so using a bounded solver (such as scipy.optimize.minimize using method='L-BFGS-B' might help to keep things under control.  Note that to find roots with a minimizer you use the square of your function.  If the found minimum is not close to zero (for you to define based on the problem), the real minima might be a complex conjugate pair.

Good luck.